# Particle in circular path in central field

Tags: energy-conservation, orbital-motion

Say a particle moves in a circular path $z(t)$ in a central field with force given by $f=-V'(r) \bar{z}$ where $\bar{z}$ is the normalization of $z(t)$ and $r$ is the distance from the origin.

$$z(t) =k(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t))).$$
Why must it hold that:
$$\theta'(t)=\sqrt{\frac{mk}{V'(k)}}$$ where $k$ is the radius of the orbit?

---

I've tried thinking about angular momentum being preserved, and Kepler's second law, but I can't work this out.

I see that:
$$f=-V'(r)\bar{z}=-V'(r)(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t)))=ma,$$
$$\implies a=\frac{-V'(r)}{m}(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t)))$$
but can't see if this helps.

Comment: So I'm unsure about the posing of your problem.  if $f= -V'(r) \bar{z}$, that means $V'(r)$ has dimensions of force/length.  Then if $m$ has dimension mass, $k$ has dimension length, then your expression for $\dot{\theta}$ has dimensions of (length*time^2) ^(1/2), which doesn't match the expected dimensions of $t^{-1}$.

Comment: May be the inverse one ???  :   $\theta'(t)=\sqrt{\dfrac{V'(k)}{mk}}$

Comment: @CDCM : $\,\bar{z}=\dfrac{z}{\Vert z \Vert}\,$ is a dimensionless unit vector, so $\,V'(r)\,$ has dimension of force $\,\mathrm{MLT^{-2}}$.

Comment: @Frobenius ahh I see, I was thinking "normalized z" was code for $|z|$.  Shouldn't $\bar{z}$ be a vector for it to make any sense?  Ahh I see your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the centripetal acceleration - this must balance the force, for the particle to stay in circular motion.

$$F_{C}= m \frac{v^2}{r} = |-V'(r) \bar{z}| = V'(k)$$

Where I have used the fact $\bar{z}$ is a unit vector.  Rearranging gives us that $v = \sqrt{\frac{kV'(k)}{m}}$

Now consider that for circular motion, $v=r\dot{\theta}$, so we get
$\dot{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{V'(k)}{m k}}$

(This is the inverse of the expression you've given, but as per the comments, this way it has the correct dimensions of $T^{-1}$, so your given expression can't be correct.)